# Why isn't buffer size always an integer multiple of 4096 when reading file line by line?

Tags: go

The sample code is,

```
// test.go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        println("Usage:", os.Args[0], "")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fileName := os.Args[1]
    fp, err := os.Open(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(2)
    }
    defer fp.Close()
    r := bufio.NewScanner(fp)
    var lines []string
    for r.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, r.Text())
    }
}
```

c:\>go build test.go

c:\>test.exe test.txt

Then I monitored its process using process monitor when executing it, part of the output is:

```
test.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS      Offset: 4,692,375, Length: 8,056
test.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS      Offset: 4,700,431, Length: 7,198
test.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS      Offset: 4,707,629, Length: 8,134
test.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS      Offset: 4,715,763, Length: 7,361
test.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS      Offset: 4,723,124, Length: 8,056
test.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS      Offset: 4,731,180, Length: 4,322
test.exe  ReadFile  END OF FILE  Offset: 4,735,502, Length: 8,192
```

The equivalent java code is,

```
//Test.java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try
  {
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
  {
   ;
  }
  }catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println(e);
  }
 }
}
```

c:\>javac Test.java

c:\>java Test

Then part of the monitoring output is:

```
java.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS       Offset: 4,694,016, Length: 8,192
java.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS       Offset: 4,702,208, Length: 8,192
java.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS       Offset: 4,710,400, Length: 8,192
java.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS       Offset: 4,718,592, Length: 8,192
java.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS       Offset: 4,726,784, Length: 8,192
java.exe  ReadFile  SUCCESS       Offset: 4,734,976, Length: 526
java.exe  ReadFile  END OF FILE   Offset: 4,735,502, Length: 8,192
```

As you see, the buffer size in java is 8192 and it read 8192 bytes each time.Why is the Length in Go changing during each time reading file?

I have tried `bufio.ReadString('\n')`,`bufio.ReadBytes('\n')`and both of them have the same problem.

**[Update]**
I have tested the sample in C,

```
//test.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        FILE * fp;
        char * line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;
        fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
                printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
        }
        if (line)
                free(line);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is similar with java code(the buffer size is 65536 on my system).**So why Go is so different here?**

Comment: I suspect that the Go code uses a different IO strategy than the Java code. It probably reads as many bytes as there is space in its buffer left (there might be bytes from a previous read left).

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks for your timely reply.I tried other languages such as perl and it also return a multiple of 4096(it is 4096 on my system) each time reading. IIRC,system page size is 4096 so maybe returning a multiple of 4096 will get better performance.

Comment: Did you actually test it and see if you gain performance or not? you're forgetting about the the system's read ahead and such.

Comment: @OneOfOne No,i didn't.I am curious about the difference between Go and other languages on this problem.

Comment: @Lee LG There shouldn't be that much of a performance difference. The operating system usually maintains a read-ahead buffer of about 4 kilobytes to catch cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading `bufio.Scan`'s [source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/bufio/scan.go?s=4436:4465#L161) shows that while the buffer size is 4096, it reads depending on how much "empty" space is left in it, specifically this part:

```
n, err := s.r.Read(s.buf[s.end:len(s.buf)])
```

Now performance wise, I'm almost positive whatever file system you're using will be smart enough to read-ahead and cache the data, so the buffer size shouldn't make that much of a difference.

Comment: Ok.Maybe my worry is unnecessary. :)

Answer (score 1):

This *may* be the reason:

In all of the examples you cite, the `Scan` function output is determined by line-endings.

Go's default scan function splits by line (http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Scan):

> the default split function breaks the input into lines with line termination stripped

And `bufio.ReadString('\n')` and `bufio.ReadBytes('\n')` have the same problem due to the `\n` character.

Try removing all newlines from your test file and testing if it still gives non 4096 multiples on the `READFILE` records.

As some have suggested, what you're seeing may actually be due to the IO strategy used by the `bufio` package.

Comment: Yep,it will return 4096 multiples after removing all newlines.I have tested that.In fact,bufio.Read(p []byte) worked as i expected.However,as you see the java sample code above,it used readLine() function to buffered read file line by line and still give 4096 multiples.

Comment: I'd guess that the Java version may be padding the buffer, or that the Java read function always reads 4096 byte chunks. If it's separating the input by lines, then the line lengths should, IMHO, be equal for the buffer lengths to be equal.